# Seeminlgy odd behavior in print statement for multiple tabs

Tags: python

I have looked this up and can't seem to figure out why it's happening.

```
print "Percentage of A\tB\tC\tD"
#prints: Percentage of A B      C        D
```

However,

```
print "Percentage of  A\tB\tC\tD"
#prints: Percentage of  A        B       C        D
```

Two questions:

1. Why does the additional space between `of` and `A` make a difference?
2. Why aren't the space intervals between the letters equivalent in either of the prints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How tabs are handled depends on the terminal or console. Often, they indent to specific tab stops; predefined columns regardless of where the tab was printed.

E.g. if there are tab stops every 8 spaces, printing a tab at column 12 means the cursor skips to column 16, and does *not* skip 8 spaces to column 20.

With the addition of a space you made the tab fill out to the *next* tab stop at position 24:

```
>>> len('Percentage of A')
15
>>> len('Percentage of  A')
16
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  So should I just use a certain number of spaces then if I want to have a precise amount of spacing?

Comment: Indeed, spaces give you precise... spacings.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use string formatting and specify the width of each field 
(e.g. {0:8} {1:8} etc)